# How to add a Gmail account to Geary?

Tags: gmail, email-client

I spent time looking for the way to configure gmail account on geary email client, with no success but is there a way to configure it now?

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

To add an account, click the **Geary** appmenu, then **Accounts** and the Accounts window will appear. You can then click the **+** button to add a new account.

To add a GMail account, simply select **GMail** from the **Service**  account type list, and type in your GMail email address and password. Note that you may need to adjust your Google settings per the FAQ: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/FAQ#Using_Google.2BIBk-s_2-Step_authentication

Answer (score 1):

Just ran in to the same thing, it is on Google's side. You have to allow less secure apps here: [Google's my account](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps)